# Grails: Search with inheritance in domain class

Tags: grails, grails-orm, hibernate-criteria

I have this two domain models in my Grails application

```
class Pet {
    String prop1
    String prop2
}
```

and this

```
class Cat extends Pet {
    String prop3
    String prop4
}
```

Now, in my app, I have many classes that is extending `Pets` and I want to search `Pet` with criteria, specifying some properties that cannot exists in other pets.

How can I make possible this operation? If I try to make a search, when a result not contains the property, raise an exception.

Comment: Sorry. I corrected. Thanks Shashank. Can you answer the question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do is impossible due to how object-oriented programming works.

```
class Foo { }
class Bar extends Foo { }
```

In this example, an instance of `Bar` *is a* `Foo` also. But, an instance of `Foo` **is not a** `Bar`. In other words, a super-class does not *know* anything about its subclasses, where as a subclass *knows* about its super-class.

Back to your example, you cannot access `prop3` nor `prop4` from `Pet` simply because they are not `Pet` properties.

### Working toward a solution

Given your classes as they are, I agree with Shashank Agrawal's solution. An SQL (not HQL or any other GORM query) is the only way to access all of the properties (actually the columns) by querying the `pet` table. Of course, this assumes you're using the default table-per-hierarchy inheritance. It will not work with table-per-subclass inheritance.

Given the assumption of table-per-hierarchy means you're already accepting nullable properties in all of `Pet`'s subclasses. It's a requirement. So, what you can do is

1. Abandon the subclasses
2. Put all of the properties in `Pet`
3. Add a property to `Pet` to specify the pet type.

Note that this is basically what [table-per-hierarchy](http://emmanuelrosa.com/articles/grails-domain-class-inheritance/) already does at the database level. The difference is that it would not be inheritance, which makes all of the properties available from `Pet`.

```
def pets = Pet.withCriteria { eq('prop3', 'whatever') }
```

Answer (score 2):

I think, the thing you are trying is not possible. But you can achieve it using two queries:

First do a lower level query:

```
// Inject the bean
def sessionFactory

String statement = "select id from pet where prop1 = 'foo' or prop3 = 'bar'";
def session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
def queryResult = session.createSQLQuery(statement)
```

Since the parent class `Pet` will have all the fields so doing the above lower level query with any field will work.

Now, get the domain instances using ids:

```
def pets = Pet.getAll(queryResult)
```

Comment: No, because I need to make a search (with criteria) from Pet. I have many pets (Monkey, Dolphin, Dogs, etc). If I try to make a search with a property of specific pet, when the query return an object without this property, the operation fail...